# Django query: Want to count an empty value

Tags: python, django, view, count

I seem to have a problem trying to count. I have a list item where each item can store many statuses, although I am only interested in it's latest status only. Now look at my views.

```
storage_items = StorageItem.objects\
                .filter(client=client_id,itemstatushistory__isnull=False)\
                .distinct()

total_items_in_stock = [item for item in storage_items \
                        if item.itemstatushistory_set.latest().status.description \
                        not in ['Destroyed','Permanent Retrieval']]
```

`total_items_in_stock` shows all items which do not have a latest status called `Destroyed` and `Permanent Retrieval`. There is a problem with this however.

Suppose I have some items in my database - say item1 {in, out, destroyed}, item2 = {destroyed, in}, item3 = {permanent retrieve}, item4 = {}.  Because it looks for the latest status, it will print {item2}. I now want to print item4 as well in the total items in staock. Basically item4 is an item without a status. But since it has not been `Destroyed` or `Permanent` Retrieval it needs to be included in the list. But I can't seem to find a way out of this. I hope I have made everything clear.

Template

```
{{total_items_in_stock|length}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you could add an `in_stock`-method to your `StorageItem` class.

Something along these lines:

```
def in_stock(self):
    if 'destroyed' and 'permanent_retrieval' not in self.itemstatushistory_set.latest().status.description:
        return True
```

Then you could simplify your list comprehension:

```
total_items_in_stock = [item for item in storage_items if item.in_stock()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
storage_items = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(client=client_id).distinct()

total_items_in_stock = [item for item in storage_items
        if not item.itemstatushistory_set.exists() or 
           item.itemstatushistory_set.latest().status.description not in ['Destroyed','Permanent Retrieval']]
```

Comment: seem to be getting an invalid syntax for some reason on the part where you define `total_items_in_stock`